# I am using a MDI application. I want to set the start position of a formShow

Tags: c#, forms, positioning, mdi

In my application when i create a new form it pops up over my old one, i would like to set its start up position to be next to the form currently displaying.

How can i set form start up position.

This is what iv got at the moment:

```
this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
```

But i want to do something along the lines of:

```
this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.left(350);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before opening the form set

```
this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.Manual; 
this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 20); // Or set your desidered location
```